# How do I manually trigger wx.Frame close event (wxPython)?

Tags: wxpython

I want to log upon error and exit the wxPython script and for that I need to trigger `wx.EVT_BUTTON.typeId` event id: `wx.ID_CLOSE`

I have OnExit defined:

```
b_exit = wx.Button(self.statusBar, wx.ID_CLOSE, "Exit")
b_exit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)
...
def OnExit(self, evt)
   self.Destroy()
```

How do I  generate and propagate wx.ID_CLOSE event from my code?

I tried but it did not work:

`wx.PyCommandEvent(wx.EVT_BUTTON.typeId, wx.ID_CLOSE)`

Answer (score 0):

changing `OnExit` to

```
def OnExit(self, evt)
   self.Close()
```

will trigger the EVT_CLOSE event. Make sure you call `event.Skip()` from the bound close method. `Destroy` is automatically called for `wx.Frame` after the frame is closed.

Side note: To trigger an event manually see [wx.PostEvent](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/events_overview.html)

Comment: do you have working example for "To trigger an event manually"?

Comment: That link does. Halfway down the page. Search for wx.PostEvent. You create the event and then call wx.PostEvent(target_window, evt)

Comment: link is a doc, i can find doc. i need couple of lines of code that answers my question

Comment: anytime, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see your code, it's difficult to know.
Hopefully, this small example of defining your own event, will allow you to work it out. I have to admit, it took me a while to get my head around it at first.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent
NewEvent, EVT_MY_EVENT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
CMD_ID = wx.NewId()
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame()
        return True

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None, title="Window", pos = (100,150), size =(250,200))
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.button1 = wx.Button(self, CMD_ID, label="Button 1")
        sizer.Add(self.button1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton,id=CMD_ID)
        self.Bind(EVT_MY_EVENT, self.OnMyEvent)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

    def OnButton(self, event):
        id = event.GetId()
        event = NewEvent(action="perform a defined action",button=id,other_setting=1234)
        wx.PostEvent(self, event)

    def OnMyEvent(self, event):
        button = event.button
        action = event.action
        other = event.other_setting
        print "event button number", button
        print "event action request", action
        print "event other", other

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```